# How will I get the time taken by a django orm query?

Tags: python, django, django-orm

**How will I get the time taken by a django orm query?**

Also, which of the following queries will be faster?

`ShipmentPPTLMapping.objects.get(shipment_id = shipment_id)`

**OR**  `ShipmentPPTLMapping.objects.filter(shipment_id = shipment_id)[0]`

Also for these queries. Which one is faster

`ShipmentPPTLMapping.objects.filter(pptl_id = pptl_id).exclude(bag_seal_status = 'close').count())`

**OR**     `ShipmentPPTLMapping.objects.filter(pptl_id = pptl_id,bag_seal_status = 'open').count())`

Answer (score 1):

One option is to use [django-debug-toolbar](https://github.com/django-debug-toolbar/django-debug-toolbar): it measures every query done on every view.

It is a *must* on any django app.

Regarding the other questions:

1. I would say they are equivalent. In Django code, `get` uses `filter` and retrieves the first element.
2. should also be equivalent because `filter` and `exclude` are just different names for `filter(Q(...))` and `filter(~Q())` and chaining is equivalent to have a comma: the queries are connected with by `AND`.
   However, because in one you are using `"open"` and in the other `"close"`, this can have an impact in how the particular backend will perform, and AFAIK this difference can only be measured by profiling.

Comment: I didnt understand your answer to my second question. Please explain again. PS: the second question contains 2 sets of questions, each having 2 similar actions but different syntax.

Comment: I see. I think you should clarify in the question then. I will edit my answer.

Comment: Ohh. I edited my qestion. Please answer for them thanks